# Conditionally selecting a field or static string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, conditional-statements

I have two tables **items** and **sale_invoice_items** , items has a flag indicating if the item expires, and sale_invoice_items has the expiry date.
now when doing SELECT to return an invoice I'm doing:

```
select  items.name as f1,  IF( items.expiry =TRUE,  sale_invoice_items.expiry, '-') as f2    
from sale_invoices, sale_invoice_items, items where  sale_invoices.id = 3 and sale_invoice_items.invoice_id = sale_invoices.id and items.id = sale_invoice_items.item_id
```

So it the item expires, then return the expiry date in the field, otherwise, just write "-"

The item name is returned ok, but the expiry is not, it is returning a byte array instead.

What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select
....
, case when items.expiry = true then 
     sales_invoice_items.expiry 
else 
     '-' 
end as expiry
....
from
....
```

you need to make sure that the data types of

```
sales_invoice_items.expiry
```

and

```
'-'
```

are the same i.e. characters. You can use the conversion functions here

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

to achieve this.

If you want a date returned, then you need to decide which value you expect for the "other" case: a dummy date, a null....?

Comment: Thanks, the format must match in both cases, that was my mistake, as the expiry is a datetime format, while "-" is a string. replacing sale_invoice_items.expiry with DATE_FORMAT(sale_invoice_items.expiry, '%d-%m-%y') did the trick